# Using 8.3 path names with pdfLaTeX

Tags: pdftex, windows, paths

I am trying to run `pdfLaTex` on a file that is in a path stored in an environment variable in my Windows environment (e.g. the `%TEMP%` directory). The path is stored using it's 8.3 DOS name. This seems to upset `pdfLaTeX` and it breaks the path name at the first `~`.

Is it somehow possible to `pdfLaTeX` using the 8.3 path name of the source? Below is a short command line extract that shows the problem:

```
C:\>echo \stop > "c:\Documents and Settings"\test.tex

C:\>REM This works

C:\>pdflatex "c:\Documents and Settings\test.tex"
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/W32TeX)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(c:/Documents and Settings/test.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <3.9k> and hyphenation patterns for 78 languages loaded.
 )
No pages of output.
Transcript written on test.log.

C:\>REM This does not work

C:\>pdflatex c:\DOCUME~1\test.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/W32TeX)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
! I can't find file `c:/DOCUME'.
<to be read again>
                   \protect
<*> c:/DOCUME~
              1/test.tex
(Press Enter to retry, or Control-Z to exit)
Please type another input file name:
! Emergency stop.
<to be read again>
                   \protect
<*> c:/DOCUME~
              1/test.tex
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on texput.log.

C:\>REM But the file is there

C:\>dir c:\DOCUME~1\test.tex
 Volume in drive C is OS
 Volume Serial Number is C642-601C

 Directory of c:\DOCUME~1

06-06-2014  18:42                 8 test.tex
               1 File(s)              8 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  93.225.000.960 bytes free

C:\>
```

Comment: use `\string~` or locally put `\catcode\`\~=12` to stop `~` being active

Comment: @DavidCarlisle But this is when I call `pdfLaTeX` in the Command Promt or from a `bat` file. I can't put `\string` in the path name as it would be interpreted as a directory. Am I missing something?

Comment: I have cygwin rather than native windows texlive but even on windows you must be able to do `pdflatex '\def\foo{zz}\input file'` can't you? I've never seen a TeX where you can't use tex syntax on the command line....  or you could use pdflatex with no argument then use \input docume\string~1/test  at the `*` prompt

Comment: or yoou could set TEXINPUTS to be ` %TEMP%;  `  then `pdflatex test` should work and you don't need to pass the `~` to tex at all

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes. This works: `pdflatex \input{c:/DOCUME\string~1/test.tex}`. I should have thought about that myself.

Comment: I'm confused how come `\input` means input but you say an unguarded `\string` would take `\ ` as a directory separator?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle If I do `pdflatex c:\DOCUME\string~1\test.tex`, `pdfLaTeX` stops with `! I can't find file "c:/DOCUME/string".`. `\input` is not a valid path name but `c:\input` or `c:\string` are.

Comment: "8.3 DOS"? Please elaborate.

Comment: Something odd here, I'd say, as @DavidCarlisle's point is about `\input`, _i.e._ 'inside' LaTeX where `~` is active, whereas parsing the command line should be a file operation where TeX conventions don't apply. Are you using TeX Live or MiKTeX (doubt the latter will go wrong here!).

Comment: It's not a good idea to compile a document from another folder and by using an absolute path:  inputs will not be found and outputs can be anywhere. I would always first switch to the document folder and then you can call pdflatex test and don't need to worry about path names.

Comment: @JosephWright the command line is interpreted as TeX so you can go `pdflatex \def\foo{xx}\input file`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, but only once the binary has decided it's not just a file name, otherwise you couldn't do `pdflatex foo` you'd have to do `pdflatex "\input foo"`.

Comment: @JosephWright true

Comment: @Sverre this is the classical short file names for files and folders with 8 characters followed by a dot and a 3 character extension. In Windows a folder with a long name can be accessed using the first 6 characters followed by tilde and a number. See e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8.3_filename

Comment: @JosephWright I use TeXlive 2013. I find it a bid odd that the input path and filename is parsed by TeX. I would think passing a valid full path to a tex file should just compile the file. But I don't know if this is by design?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I was experimenting with a script that compiled in a temporary folder and using the `--output-directory` switch to direct the output to the desired location. The path to the folder came from another function in short form which made `pdflatex` barf unexpectedly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
pdflatex \input{c:/DOCUME\string~1/test.tex}
```

or probably

```
set TEXINPUTS=%TEMP%;
pfdflatex test
```

will also work.

I would also have expected

```
pdflatex c:/DOCUME\string~1/test.tex
```

to work but I can't test on a native windows tex.

Comment: The last one works too, but not if using `\` as the normal path separator.

Answer (score 2):

Just for reference: I've reported the issue to the TeXlive mailing list. See [here](http://tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2014-June/035499.html) for the start of the thread.

Short 8.3 file names will be supported in [TeXlive 2015](http://tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2014-June/035507.html).